# What causes 201xs HDDs to live less than 200xs ones?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, lifespan

There is a common opinion (on forums and e-market aggregator websites) that nowadays HDDs live less than the ones from 200xs. I wonder

- if this opinion is true;
- are there any researches confirming or declining this statement;
- what are the causes of this fall of reliability (except obvious conspiracy-theoretic ones that HDD/SSD manufacturers need to make SSD more competitive to HDDs)

Comment: This is not a question that can be authoritatively answered by anyone here at Super User.

Answer (score 2):

The best freely-available large sample research is that done by Backblaze, though it probably doesn't go back far enough.

They do a report every quarter, see https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-failure-rates-q1-2017/ for starters